# Iron bar entering solenoid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity, electromagnetic-induction

I found this MC question that asks about a soft iron bar entering a solenoid:
[image]

At first, my answer was (B) because the iron bar should increase the magnetic field induced by coil M and, according to Lenz's law, this magnetic field should oppose the original current, making the lamp dimmer. Also, the magnetic field created by M should then induce a current in N in the opposite direction to the current in M (also Lenz's law), so since the current in M is right to left, then it should be left to right in N. I wasn't too confident in my answer though.

Then, I noticed that they had drawn a DC power source in M. This would indicate no changing magnetic field, thus no current induced into either M or N. This would mean that the lamp doesn't change brightness and there is no direction of current in N. Right? Is this just a mistake in the question, or am I missing something?
Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Regarding the power source: the one drawn here is a *constant voltage* (not constant current) source. So the current through it can change; it maintains a fixed voltage difference between its two sides.

Comment: @AndrewSteane Thanks. That makes sense. Do you know the answer to the question also?